# ResultSetMetadata column types for count()/sum()

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In MySQL select:

`count(BIGINT)` returns type=-5 (BigInteger), I expected `Long`

`sum(SMALLINT)` returns type=3 (BigDecimal), I expected `Integer`

Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of -5 indicates `java.sql.Types.BIGINT`, which is the JDBC/SQL equivalent of a Java `long`, so this value is entirely expected.

As to why `SUM` is mapped to 3, or `java.sql.DECIMAL`, I'm not sure. It might just be that is what MySQL does when summing not floating-point types.